# Select same row twice, and make the copy immutable

Tags: mysql, select, join, null, immutability

Due to me performing a left join that sometimes does not deliver a result, the ID of my "first" table somehow gets set to 0. I now want to select the ID twice, and make the copy immutable, so that I can still access it even when the join fails.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID 
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table1.ID = table3.ID
```

Each row in table1 only has the same ID in either table2 or table3, so, for each row, one of the two joins will "fail". Here's what I get as result (Mock result):

```
+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|  ID  | Table1Col1 | Table1Col2 | Table2Col1 | Table2Col2 | Table3Col1 | Table3Col2 |
+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| NULL | Something  | Something  | NULL       | NULL       | Something  | Something  |
| NULL | SomeValue  | SomeValue  | Something  | Something  | NULL       | NULL       |
+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

What I want to achieve: Keep "ID" from being NULL.

(Also, selecting "table1.ID as MyID, *" gives me a SQL Error)

(Selecting values explicitely is out of question for design reasons)

Comment: what's the error can you include?

Comment: I think "immutable" is not the right word, since `*` will just provide one ID field, which might just be the wrong one. Giving the error message would have been helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query *should* work, naming the fields explicitly ...

```
SELECT table1.ID, table1.Table1Col1, table1.Table1Col2, 
       table2.Table2Col1, table2.Table2Col2, 
       table3.Table3Col1, Table3.Table3Col2
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON (table1.ID=table2.ID)
LEFT JOIN table3 ON (table1.ID=table3.ID)
```

**update** for wildcards: You have to provide a table when `*` is not the only select "column".

```
SELECT table1.ID as MyID, table1.*, table2.*, table3.*
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON (table1.ID=table2.ID)
LEFT JOIN table3 ON (table1.ID=table3.ID)
```

beware, that identical columns will appear multiple times this way so whatever processes the result should probably expect that. In PHP for example I believe the last value wins (if accessed by columnname).

Comment: Yes, if I could name them explicitely, that is. I forgot to mention in my post, but the future web administrator should be able to add table's or columns without having to change the query code. (That may sound a little weird, but when using '*' it works completely fine)

Comment: well it doesn't work completely fine, or you wouldn't ask the question? ^^. Please post the error message you got when trying the renaming thing.

Comment: Well, I meant everything else, but yeah, you're right :P. I would have posted the error if it meant anything. I only get `You have an error in your SQL syntax near "* FROM ..."`. Or I'm too stupid to use MySQL the right way. I don't know.

Comment: Thanks! This makes things a little bit easier, even though I'll still have to use one or a few additional loops. Too bad that you can't use * with other columns too.

Comment: I actually solved it now by renaming the ID field from my table1 to CID, which lets the result have a value on CID and NULL on ID. But your answer still is the right one, obviously. I'll upvote it once I have enough reputation to do so, lol.